How to do an inner join?
I have an ASP.NET Core project where I am using Entity Framework to manage database queries. I want to know how I can do an INNER JOIN between two tables with Entity Framework, in this case the user table with the type_access_user table. I would like to return the name of the type_access_user in a query made in the user.
I'm new to C# and Entity Framework, I need help with this.
public class Type_access_user
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string? name { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string? uid { get; set; }
    public int? type_access_user_id { get; set; }
}

Code to return data:
return await _context.User
                     .Select(user => new User
                                     {
                                         id = user.id,
                                         uid = user.uid,
                                         type_access_user_id = user.type_access_user_id,
                                         createdAt = user.createdAt,
                                         updatedAt = user.updatedAt,
                                     }).ToListAsync();

I need something similar to this SQL query:
SELECT  
    us.id, us.uid, us.type_access_user_id,
    tyac.name AS type_access_user_name,
    us.createdAt, us.updatedAt
FROM 
    User AS us
INNER JOIN 
    Type_access_user AS tyac ON tyac.id = us.type_access_user_id


Add navigation properties to your model.


how I can do an INNER JOIN between two tables with Entity Framework, in this case the user table with type_access_user, I would like to return the name of the type_access_user in a query made in the user.

According to your scenario, in order to perform an inner join between two tables (User and TypeAccessUser) using Entity Framework and return the TypeAccessUser name in a query made on the User, you could try in following way.
First of all, you can convert the T-SQL to relevant Linq query keeping your POCO class as it is.
Demo model:
public class TypeAccessUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Uid { get; set; }
    public int? TypeAccessUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

Demo controller with sample data:
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var typeAccessUsers = new List<TypeAccessUser>
    {
        new TypeAccessUser { Id = 1, Name = "Admin", CreatedAt = DateTime.Now, UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now },
        new TypeAccessUser { Id = 2, Name = "User", CreatedAt = DateTime.Now, UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now }
    };

    var users = new List<User>
    {
        new User { Id = 1, Uid = "user1", TypeAccessUserId = 1, CreatedAt = DateTime.Now, UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now },
        new User { Id = 2, Uid = "user2", TypeAccessUserId = 2, CreatedAt = DateTime.Now, UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now }
    };

   
    var result = from user in users
                 join typeAccessUser in typeAccessUsers on user.TypeAccessUserId equals typeAccessUser.Id
                 select new
                 {
                     UserId = user.Id,
                     UserUid = user.Uid,
                     TypeAccessUserId = user.TypeAccessUserId,
                     TypeAccessUserName = typeAccessUser.Name,
                     CreatedAt = user.CreatedAt,
                     UpdatedAt = user.UpdatedAt
                 };

    return View(result);
}

As you can see, the join clause specifies the joining of the two collections. It matches each user object with a typeAccessUser object where user.TypeAccessUserId equals typeAccessUser.Id. This is equivalent to the SQL INNER JOIN operation, ensuring only the records with matching keys from both collections are included in the result.
View:
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
<h1>User List</h1>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>UID</th>
            <th>Type Access User ID</th>
            <th>Type Access User Name</th>
            <th>Created At</th>
            <th>Updated At</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.UserId</td>
                <td>@item.UserUid</td>
                <td>@item.TypeAccessUserId</td>
                <td>@item.TypeAccessUserName</td>
                <td>@item.CreatedAt</td>
                <td>@item.UpdatedAt</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

Output:


Note: Please refer to this official document, if you need additional details.

So many text for just one query. Bad here that Include is just not needed. Select and Include are mutually exclusive operators.

Yeah, just tried to explains both ways in order to assit the OP better, sometimes, only query or direct solution creates confusions, First apporach mostly suitable based on the given code.

Yes, please reduce it to the essentials. ASP.Net is not essential here, everything related to it is noise, so are the screenshots. Also it doesn't matter if it works on in-memory objects. What matters is the generated SQL. Then you'll notice that option 2 does not produce an INNER JOIN.

@GertArnold, thanks for the suggestion, I have updated the answer.

@MdFaridUddinKiron, please, when you are answering EF Core questions, do not use examples with local collections. It is different things. EF Core may generate ineffective SQL but in LINQ to Objects everything is logical.

I managed to do it here with this example, thank you very much
